# Instagram API Rate Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, instagram

I'm currently using the Instagram API to like photos and follow users. I'm passing in the access token to make the requests, but for some reason I keep getting client request limit reached. I'm not sure why since the requests are being sent with an access token saved when users authenticate with my app.

here's the gem I'm using to connect to the API in my Rails app: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

```ruby
def self.follow_users(token, tags, user_id)
  tags.each do |hashtag|
    Instagram.tag_recent_media(hashtag.content).data.each do |data|
      Instagram.follow_user(data.user.id, :access_token => token)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the user's access token? Or are you passing your own (or your app's) `access_token`?

If you're passing your own, the reason you're seeing the rate limit error is because Instagram limits [Follows to 60/h and Likes to 150/h](http://imranakbar.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/rate-limit-exceeded-instagram-error/). You can check the number remaining by inspecting the return HTTP header, and looking for [`x-ratelimit-remaining`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/AXy39iOqkPw).

Sample response:

```
{
    "error_type": "APIError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Client request limit reached",
    "x-ratelimit-limit": "150",
    "x-ratelimit-remaining": "3"
}
```

Comment: I'm passing the access token that I'm getting from the user. I'm passing the current user's token from the controller to the model. I'll update the question with some code.

Comment: Where in the flow are you getting the error? Ultimately, if you're following in a loop like that, you're probably going well over the 60/h follow limit, even if it is per-user.

Comment: I'm getting the error on the follow section. Yeah, ideally I'd like to run this code in a rake task every hour.

Comment: I've had a lot of experience handling it, and you're just not going to be able to work around it. If it's throwing back the x-ratelimit-remaining at 0, you've used all of your follow API calls for that hour. I know someone who's created separate apps to handle it, but that violates the ToU and you could get yourself banned.

Comment: Interesting, seems like these guys have executed something similar successfully though: https://github.com/oh-moore/followpie

Comment: Just because it exists doesn't mean it doesn't violate the ToU ;) Implement at your own risk.